# How to fix Systembootorder

Tags: linux, linux-mint, uefi, boot-loader, grub-legacy

I tried to install Linux Mint Cinnamon on my Acer laptop, but after the installation there comes up a grub bootloader screen with this text.

https://ibb.co/P9r0hpw

So what can I do? It's now enough for me if I can format my harddisk and install only windows.

Old System: Windows 10 Bios Legacy Mode

Installation from Linux Mint in EFI mode.

Comment: Related: [askubuntu.com/questions/1042747](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747)

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. They write system info differently onto drive. Or grub can only boot another system in same boot mode. Also Windows in BIOS mode must be on MBR partitioned drive. UEFI strongly suggests gpt. But Ubuntu will let you use MBR for UEFI, but then you cannot have Windows as ESP - efi system partition must have boot flag. And Windows on its BIOS boot partition must have boot flag. And only one boot flag per drive. Better to backup everything important and reinstall in UEFI boot mode. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012.

Comment: Hi. How can i backup my system? With live Linux ? How can/should I install Windows? Normally boot from a usb drive and then normal isntall? What should I do with my Bios?